# What's the easiest way to do something like delegate multicast in F#

Tags: f#

Currently I use this and it works fine:

```
let mutable notify = fun x -> x
let wrap f i = f(i); i

let a x = printf "%A" x
notify <- notify >> (wrap a)

notify "ss"
```

Are there any other better approach?

and why this doesn't work?

```
let mutable notify = fun x -> x
let wrap f i = f(i); i

let a x = printf "%A" x  
let d x =
    (notify >> (wrap a)) x
notify <- d

notify "ss"
```

I am not sure why the first example doesn't trigger endless loop, but the second does.

It seems mutable function variable (point free function) has different behaviour than I expected. Where can I learn more from regarding this topic?

Answer (score 3):

Do you not want to use `MulticastDelegate`?

```
type D<'T> = delegate of 'T -> 'T
let mutable notify = D<string>(fun x -> x)
let wrap f i = f(i); i
let a x = printfn "%A" x
notify <- Delegate.Combine(notify, D<string>(wrap a)) :?> _
notify.Invoke "ss"
```

Your second example fails because `d` calls `notify`, which recurses infinitely.

Comment: I think the extra level of indirection is caused by `d`, not `>>`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the way to compose multiple handlers in the functional programming paradigm is for each handler to tail-call its first argument, passing the remainder of the arguments.  Then curry that with another handler, forming a chain or singly-linked list of handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one straightforward alternative.  If you want to represent a list of functions to call, then why not just keep a (mutable) list of functions?

```
let handlers = ResizeArray()
let notify x = 
    for f in handlers do
        f x

handlers.Add(fun x -> printf "%A" x)

notify "ss"
```